# Degree sequence in a maximal planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, hamiltonian-path

[Two isomorphic 9 vertex graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMF0Q.png) Given the ordered degree sequence of a hamiltonian circuit in a maximal planar graph. Can we have different maximal planar graphs with the same ordered degree sequence?

The hamilton circuit in both graphs have the same ordered degree sequence, but are isomorphic. Both have a 5-3 and a 5-6 edge

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? A LOT, but didn't find 1 possible/inpossible degree sequence! Given the degree sequence of the interior or the exterior polygon, then there is only 1 possibility. But merged together looks very difficult even to reconstruct the original one.

Comment: For the same MPG on 9 vertices we can have 555446445 and also 546554454 for the ordered degree sequence on 2 different hamilton circuits. But can we have two or more different MPG for some ordered sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If trying small examples doesn't work (and it doesn't, because *very* small examples don't exist), your next step should be trying out slightly larger examples with software.

Go to [Brendan McKay's graphs page](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/graphs.html) and you'll be able to download a `.g6` file of all the connected $9$-vertex planar graphs. (With $8$ or fewer, this won't work.)

From here, pick out the ones with $21$ edges, and from there the Hamiltonian ones. Finding the degree sequence along each Hamiltonian cycle of each graph that's left results in some overlap; for example, there are two graphs with the ordered degree sequence $5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6$.

[image] [image]

Here are these two planar graphs, with the corresponding Hamiltonian cycles $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,a)$ highlighted. One quick way to see that these are not isomorphic is that in the first graph, any two vertices of degree $3$ have a common neighbor; in the second graph, $d$ has neighbors $\{b,c,e\}$ but $h$ has neighbors $\{a,g,i\}$.

Comment: Are both graphs not homeomorphic? An octaeder-graph with a K4 in three non adjacent triangles.

Comment: No, there's one more possibility. (There may be several ways to get the same graph, too.)

Comment: I added an image to my question. Do you mean that both graphs are different because the degree-6 and degree-5 vertices are on  a different position?

Comment: Your question is different now; you were not asking about specific graphs before, were you? The two graphs you drew are obviously isomorphic.

Comment: Sorry, the question had to be: Are there two or more non-isomorphic hamiltonian maximal planar graphs on v vertices with the same ordered degree sequence in the hamiltonian circuit. Should I start a new thread with it?

Comment: No, that is the question as I understood it, and that is the question I answered. But your illustration has two copies of the same graph, instead. (I will add an illustration of the other graph when I get a chance.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the graphical result after I understood Misha's answer. The three 9vertex graphs have the same ordered degree sequences in the hamilton circuit. The two left are isomorphic, the two right are not.[3MPG's on 9 vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuNjg.png)